# C++ Pointer Lists and passage by reference

Tags: c++, list, stdlist

On the code below, do I  need to create an instance of my list when I use the constructor in ClassWithList?

Also, why is addToList wrong? How can I achieve that?

```
class AbstClass;
class ObjClass : AbstClass;

class ClassWithList
{
    std::list<AbstClass*> absts;
public:
    ClassWithList(); //new list?
    void addToList(ObjClass& obj)
    {
        list.push_back(obj);
    }



};
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and be much clearer about what you are trying to achieve, and what is currently happening, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Because your list is called "absts" not "list".

Comment: And you don't need to explicitly create the list in the constructor.

Comment: So the complete correction should be `absts.push_back(&obj);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It worked! Thanks.

Comment: @Erethan I rolled back your changes, since they have rendered completely useless what you've been asking for originally. You may consider accepting my answer if that fixed your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some simple corrections (explanations in comments):

```
class AbstClass;
class ObjClass : public AbstClass; // << You need to derive as public

class ClassWithList
{
    std::list<const AbstClass *> absts;
public:
    ClassWithList(); // You don't need new list, it will be allocated 
                     // already correctly at construction
    void addToList(const AbstClass& obj)
    {
        absts.insert(&obj); // << pass the address
     // ^^^^^ The member is named absts
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared a list that contains pointers to objects

```
std::list<AbstClass*> absts;
          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus the function addToList should receive pointers to objects of type `AbstClass *`

```
void addToList(AbstClass *obj)
{
    absts.push_back(obj);
    ^^^^^
}
```

As for the list then its default constructor will be called implicitly when an object of the class will be created. So you have to do nothing with the list in the class constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA What do you mean?

Comment: @Vlad Also `void addToList(ObjClass& obj)` is perfectly OK as long `&obj` is pushed into `absts`.

Comment: I think OP's list member is absts. So the add method should call absts.push_back(obj);

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is just a typo due to the operation of copy and paste.

Comment: Sorry all for that mess. I hope there are no more typos